# When setting Mapping Variables do you have to wire them all the way to the target?

Tags: informatica-powerexchange

I have a confusion on mapping variables in Informatica.

I set the variables using setVariable() and sometimes setCountVariable() but they are still at zero when I try to pass them back to the calling workflow using the postsession-success_variable_assignment.

My question: Can you set a variable anywhere in the mapping and stop there, for example in a expression, or do you have to wire it all the way to the target to get Infa to recognize it?

Can the port be an output only port, or must it be a variable port first and then moved to an output port secondly.

Comment: Check your session logs, they should show you what your variables are set to at beginning and end of the session

Either a problem that the port with setvariable is never reached for some reason (such as its part of a transformation that your data never gets routed to or an error with the later assignment)

Comment: Thanks... I will take a closer look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just output it to next transformation... It will get assigned